# How to enable swap in OpenVZ container?

Tags: virtualization, vps, openvz

### The problem

Recently I decided to rent a $1.00/month VPS. I knew there was going to be a catch for the price and the specs and I think I've found it... I cannot create swap files as they VPS provider uses OpenVZ virtualization.

### My conclusion

After doing a little bit of research, I've come to the conclusion that my VPS is inside some sort of OpenVZ container(not docker)... And I'm not sure how to create swap inside one...

So, I'm wondering if there is any possibilities of somehow enabling some sort of  VSwap?

Comment: That would probably be a question for the provider. For the most part, you don't use swap in an OpenVZ container (I think maybe you can't?). Why do you need swap?

Comment: @Spooler For memory intensive applications that require it... Such as `mariadb` and maybe `openVPN`!

Comment: Swap is not the answer. They surely won't allow you to thrash their persistent storage in return for buying less memory, and that would perform real badly anyways. If you need more memory, use more memory - especially with an OpenVZ instance in a VPS.

Comment: @Spooler For example, to use more RAM as he bought. I am not sure if OpenVZ even allows swapping. However, if there is a contract then it should deal with it. If it doesn't, then the provider should be assumed to allow it.

Comment: @Spooler I appreciate your guys advice! I'm going to contact my hosting provider about enabling something called VSwap. It's in the control panel!